# Jetbrains DataSpell managed server doesn't work with the configured python interpreter (a conda environment running theano)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, pymc3, dataspell

Jetbrains DataSpell looks almost *awesome*, but I'm having an issue with the managed servers that makes it just *alright*. I'm using a conda environment (which I've called `pymc3_env` for obvious reasons) as my interpreter. I've configured both the workspace and the project to use `pymc3_env`. When I run code in a notebook connected to a DataSpell-managed Jupyter server I get errors (specifically some quite fundamental Clang compilation errors from theano: `ld: library not found for -lSystem`). The same code in the same notebook runs fine if, instead of using a DataSpell-managed server, I activate the conda environment in a terminal, launch a Jupyter notebook server, and give DataSpell the URL. What gives?